# What episode of Naruto does the Rinnegan first appear in?

Tags: naruto

The wiki says it appears in the episode 135 of the original series, but I can't see it anywhere. What episode does it appear in? Because I need to see it.

Comment: I'm not sure I have a reason to doubt that info.  I haven't technically finished the first series, but if Akatsuki were revealed in that episode, it leaves little doubt in my mind that the Rinnegan made an appearance, even though it might *not* have been specified what it was at the time.

Answer (score 6):

It is in fact in episode 135 "[The Promise That Could Not Be Kept](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/The_Promise_That_Could_Not_Be_Kept)" (alternatively, episode 35 of season 3), as can be seen here (taken from the end of the episode, sorry about the bad quality):

> [image: Screenshot of a pair of Rinnegan, rest of the body in shadow.]

> [image: Screenshot of a single Rinnegan, looking straight at the viewer.]

You've to remember that in the earlier episodes, we did not actually see Pain, we just saw these images of the Akatsuki members. But the Rinnegan was seen already back then.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. The Rinnegan's first appearance is in episode 81 "[Sad News](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Sad_News)" of *Naruto: Shippuuden* (alternatively, episode 10 of season 4), at the timestamp 10:49.

[image: Screenshot showing the Rinnegan. The Akatsuki leader's body is not visible due to the nature of the jutsu being used, only the eyes stand out for the viewer.]

Comment: While it's true that the Rinnegan appears "properly" for the first time in this episode (in the sense that we actually see the body hosting this pair of eyes a little later at 16:18, instead of just a shadowy body), the [other answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/35919) by [Omry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/15549/omry) is correct that the Rinnegan makes an appearance in the original *Naruto* series itself in episode 135.

Comment: It is also curious that the Rinnegan "actually" appears much earlier in *Naruto: Shippūden* in [episode 10](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Sealing_Technique:_Phantom_Dragons_Nine_Consuming_Seals_(episode)), though it doesn't have the same developed form as in episode 81. Here's a screenshot from episode 10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ekN.jpg.